# DPRP is disabled for this merchant

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, paypal

What to do for `DPRP is disabled for this merchant` error?

I have generated this array with my error

```
Array
(
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2012-12-12T06:15:28Z
    [CORRELATIONID] => 20039fe211e60
    [ACK] => Failure
    [VERSION] => 75.0
    [BUILD] => 4181146
    [L_ERRORCODE0] => 11586
    [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => DPRP is disabled.
    [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => DPRP is disabled for this merchant.
    [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you're attempting to use CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile with credit card information and this is what you're getting..??

DPRP = DirectPayment Recurring Payments.  It's an additional feature that you have to get enabled on your PayPal account.  Unfortunately, they'll charge you another $30/mo for it on top of the initial Payments Pro fee, so you'll be paying a total of $60/mo to use it.

If that's ok, you can simply call PayPal and request that they enable this for you.  If you'd rather not pay that monthly fee you can get setup with Payments Advanced and use Recurring Billing instead.  It's much cheaper.

Comment: How can i check whether paypal has activated DPRP in my account? And also how can i activate the recurring billing from my account?

Comment: To check for DPRP you can simply attempt to create a profile with it again and if you get the same error you know they haven't activated it.  If you want to switch to Recurring Billing on Payments Advanced you'll need to call and have them switch your account over to that version.

Comment: But how to check the version of my account that it is compatible with DPRP. And which version is compatible with the DPRP?? Any idea regarding that?

Comment: How long ago did you sign up for Payments Pro?  If it was recent then they most likely set you up with version 3.0 which uses the PayFlow gateway instead of DoDirectPayment.  Do you use paypal.com to manage everything, or do you also have a login at manager.paypal.com?

Comment: I m using paypal.com and i call in the support there i found that the have created the account with payflow pro. So i am not able to do recurring payment.

Comment: That means you're on PayFlow then, and you should also have login credentials for manager.paypal.com.  Instead of Recuring Payments you'll use [Recurring Billing with PayFlow](https://www.x.com/sites/default/files/pp_payflowpro_recurringbilling_guide.pdf), which is essentially the same thing, just a different API.

Comment: So with the help of Manager Paypal API credential.. Will i able to do recurring payment??  or i need to change the code??

Comment: If PayFlow is what you're on then you would have to change your code to use that API instead of CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile.  If you already have CRPP code ready to go and you don't want to start over with PayFlow you can call PayPal and request that they switch your account.

Comment: No i cannot switch the account. Can you tell me how can i do recurring payment in payflow pro. Do you have API Demo for that?

Comment: I gave you a link a couple of comments ago to the PayFlow Recurring Billing documentation.